# script not running as expected when scheduled as a cronjob

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep, cron, imagemagick

I'm trying to write a script that will identify corrupt jpg images using imagemagicks identify command.  The script will run the command, grep the output for the word "Corrupt", move it to a corrupt folder if corrupt or move it to an input folder if the file appears good.

My script works as expected if I run it manually from a terminal window.  Ideally i want to run this script as a cron job however when I schedule it as a cronjob, its moving everything to the input folder...so it seems like the IF statement isn't getting evaluated correctly.  Is there something different i need to do with my script to make it work as a cronjob?

```
#!/bin/bash
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

#variables for our folders
DROP_FOLDER=~/Desktop/Drop
CORRUPT_FOLDER=corrupt_images/
INPUT_FOLDER=Input/

cd $DROP_FOLDER
for f in *.jpg
do
    if /opt/ImageMagick/bin/identify -verbose $f | /usr/bin/grep -iq "Corrupt"; then
        mv "$f" $CORRUPT_FOLDER
    else
        mv "$f" $INPUT_FOLDER
    fi
done
```

I am scheduling in crontab with

```
*/2 * * * * cd ~ && ./myscript.sh
```

Comment: Add to your question your cronline which runs your script.

Comment: Add full path to `identify` and `grep` in your script.

Comment: I tried adding full paths for identify and grep commands with no luck.  also tried adding same LANG env variable value as I have in interactive terminal...still no luck

Comment: Its not that the script does not run via cron....its running, its just not running the same as it does when i run it manually in a terminal.  It appears to always fall to the else block

Comment: Your grep looks fine, so maybe try this: make your drop folder have just two images, one image known to be "corrupt", and another image known to be not corrupt. Then, revise your script so between "do" to "done" you just have : `identify -verbose "$f"  >> ~/log` , wait `~/log` to appear, and then immediately update your question to share the  contents of `~/log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to replace your `if` block by:

```
/opt/ImageMagick/bin/identify -verbose "$f" | /usr/bin/grep -iq "Corrupt"
if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq 0 && ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 1 ]]; then
  mv "$f" "$INPUT_FOLDER"
else
  mv "$f" "$CORRUPT_FOLDER"
fi
```

---

From  `man bash`:

> `PIPESTATUS`: An  array  variable  (see  Arrays  below)  containing  a  list of exit status values from the processes in the most-recently-executed foreground pipeline (which may contain only a single command).

Comment: I finally got this to work, only modification is i had to put double quotes around the 0 and 1 values.
    if [[ ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -eq "0" && ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq "1" ]]; then

Answer (score 1):

When you add your script as a cron job, the cron user that runs your script is different to your normal user account that you probably have been testing your script with.
So then when this command

```
DROP_FOLDER=~/Desktop/Drop
```

is run the `~` is expanded to the `$HOME` of the cron user (i.e. root) therefore you should replace `DROP_FOLDER=~/Desktop/Drop` with the full path of your intended directory.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the commands in the condition don't work as expected. To debug this, redirect the output and the error output of the identity command to a file, and observe what gets written, for example:

```
/opt/ImageMagick/bin/identify -verbose $f &> /tmp/debug.log
```

After seeing this output we should see clearer what is happening.